# Filenames for custom vim-snippets snippets

Tags: vim

I've started using `https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate` with `https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets` and am having some issues getting my own snippets to work.

My plugins are managed by Vundler and I've created a custom `.vim/snippets` folder where I've put my own `javascript.snippets` and they are loading correctly with this setup.

I would like to create a bunch of smaller snippet files like: `javascript.karma.snippets` and `javascript.angular.snippets` to help me organize them better. My issue is that my snippets will not load unless it they are in a file named `javascript.snippets`. I've looked through the `honza/vim-snippets` repo and noticed that they are able to namespace snippets this way, but I am not sure how to configure my system to load the different filenames.

The github repo has this in the FAQ, but I do not know how to check it:

`Check that your snippets file is in scope by either the filetype matching the path of the snippet file or the scope explicitly loaded.`

Answer (score 0):

I read the docs again, my file needs to be named `javascript_angular.snippets` to autoload:

[From the docs](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate#faq): `Taking "scopes" from these options, it looks in each snippets/ directory in 'runtimepath' for files named scope.snippets, scope/*.snippets, or scope_*.snippets.`